# как передать параметр на другой action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я новичок в ралсах и возникла такая пробема.

у меня есть контроллер home и action index откуда я получаю данные и вывожу на главную страницу:

```
def index
 @best_product = Meva.order(reting: :desc).limit(4)
end
```

и action продукты где должен открываться выбранный продукт.

```
def product
 @category = Meva.find(params[:id])
end
```

в странице index так передаю параметр на  action продукты

```
<% @best_product.each do |product| %>
         <%= link_to product.name, home_product_path(product) %>
<% end %>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в описание вопроса то, как вы объявляете роут для экшена `product` и то, какие ссылки приблизительно вам  генерирует `link_to`.

Comment: get 'home/product'  и <a href="/home/product.5">Яблоко</a>

Comment: попробуйте изменить роут на `get 'home/product/:id'`

Comment: при роут выводит ошибку: in `check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)

Comment: А, да, совсем забыл, роут еще нужно направить на экшен в таком случае. А если так: `get 'home/product/:id', to: 'home#product'` ?

Comment: исчез home_product_path.  выводит ошибку: NoMethodError in Home#index

Comment: `get 'home/product/:id', to: 'home#product', as: :home_product`. Здесь есть исчерпывающий гайд по роутам - http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing